# Real time %iowait monitor

Tags: linux

I am new to scripting and i know the question below is very simple but not getting anything..

sar command gives the below output,

```
root@virt01:~# sar 1 1

Linux 3.19.0-42-generic (virt01.ubuntu.com)     13/02/16        _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

12:19:55        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     
%idle

12:19:56        all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    
100.00
Average:        all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
root@virt01:~#
```

Just want to how to check for particular value for example:%iowait and send mail alert if its exceeds 50.

If you can help it would be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the `sar 1 1` command:

```
# sar 1 1
Linux 4.14.14 (sys.local)   02/08/2018  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)
09:38:01 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
09:38:02 PM     all      5.74      0.00      1.50      0.00      0.00     92.77
Average:        all      5.74      0.00      1.50      0.00      0.00     92.77
```

We want the %iowait column. A common string to match regex against in each row is `all` under `CPU`, so:

```
# sar 1 1 | awk '/all|iowait/{print $7}'
%iowait
0.00
0.00
```

In this case we added `iowait` to the regex to confirm that we got the correct column, `$7`. (See `man awk` for more details on awk usage.) Our next step is to save these values for use in our script:

```
# iowait=( $( sar 1 1 | awk '/all/{print $7}' ) )
```

This `var=()` syntax is for an array. See `man bash` for details. We can reference these values with ${iowait[1]}, so now we're prepared for a loop over both values:

```
# iowait=( $( sar 1 1 | awk '/all/{print $7}' ) ) ; for I in ${iowait[*]} ; do \
   echo $I ; \
   done 
0.25
0.00
```

Great, almost there, no we can compare these values with a conditional. This will take some extra effort, because bash prefers to compare integers rather than floats. We could multiply these by 100 before the comparison, but it's easier to use a bash shortcut to drop the decimals before the comparison. To get 12 from 12.34 in the variable `$I`, we'll use ${I%%.*} syntax. This removes the matching suffix from the variable `I`, and the regex `.*` matches anything, thus everything after the decimal. `-lt` in bash will work within a conditional: `if [ ]; then something; fi` All of this is outlined in detail in `man bash` for reference.

```
# iowait=( $( sar 1 1 | awk '/all/{print $7}' ) ) ; \
  for I in ${iowait[*]} ; do \
      if [ ${I%%.*} -lt 2 ] ; then \
         echo "$I < 2" ; \
      fi ; \
  done
0.00 < 2
0.00 < 2
```

One final addition before we send our email, lets add a specific timestamp, and see what's running during this high IO:

```
# iowait=( $( sar 1 1 | awk '/all/{print $7}' ) ) ; \
  for I in ${iowait[*]} ; do \
      if [ ${I%%.*} -lt 2 ] ; then \
         echo "$(date -Is): iowait = $I\n $(ps)" ; \
      fi ; \
  done 
2018-02-08T22:09:21-05:00: iowait = 0.25
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3431 pts/1    00:00:00 zsh
28148 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
2018-02-08T22:09:21-05:00: iowait = 0.00
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3431 pts/1    00:00:00 zsh
28150 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Of course, better ps options like `ps eaf` or `ps auxfw` can be used as you prefer for more details. No, to actally achieve the task (comparing `-gt 50`) and send the email by piping our output to `mailx`:

```
# iowait=( $( sar 1 1 | awk '/all/{print $7}' ) ) ; \
  for I in ${iowait[*]} ; do \
     if [ ${I%%.*} -gt 50 ] ; then echo "$(date -Is): iowait = $I\n $(ps)" |
        mailx -s "hi iowait" root ; \
     fi  ; \
  done
```

Hopefully this both answers your question, and demonstrates how one can build what you want through breaking the problem down step by step, leveraging the unix philsophy, it's many tools, and man pages.